# How to call a plugin in CakePHP 2.x Shell?

Tags: php, cakephp, highcharts

I'm trying to use a plugin (Highcharts) in the CakePHP 2.x shell but I doesn't work. The plugin loads in bootstrap.php `(CakePlugin::load('Highcharts'))` and works well in the application but not in the shell.

I get below error :

`Notice Error: Undefined property: MyTestShell::$Highcharts in [/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp/vendors/cakephp/cakephp/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php, line 513]`

This is my code :

```
class MyTestShell extends AppShell {

  public $components = array('Highcharts.Highcharts');

  public function main() {

    $this->out($this->makeChart());
  }


  public function makeChart() {

    $mychart = $this->Highcharts->create('TestChart', 'column');
  }

}
```

Comment: "_call a plugin_" is quite unspecific... given the shown code snippet, you are trying to access a (plugin) component!? ps, please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt` or `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: Sorry for that. It's a CakePHP version 2.9.8

Comment: Ok... and you are actually trying to access a component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my solution and it works like a charm :

```
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');
App::uses('ComponentCollection', 'Controller');
App::uses('HighchartsComponent', 'Highcharts.Controller/Component');

class MyTestShell extends AppShell {


  public function main() {

    $Collection = new ComponentCollection();
    $this->Highcharts = new HighchartsComponent($Collection);

    $this->out($this->makeChart());
  }


  public function makeChart() {

    $mychart = $this->Highcharts->create('TestChart', 'column');
  }

}
```